# Highlight selected date in Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am retrieving some dates from a database and holding them in a List ListDates (going to leave this code out but it shouldnt have any issues with the problem im trying to resolve).

The calendar highlights all days when there is a meeting scheduled.

A user **selects a date** from an ASP .Net calendar control.

In the DayRender event i have the following code

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListDates != null )
    {
        if (ListDates.Contains(e.Day.Date))
        {
            e.Cell.CssClass = "highlight";
        }

        if (ListDates.Contains(Calendar1.SelectedDate))
        {
            e.Cell.CssClass = "newHighlight";
        }
}
}
```

So at page load i get a list of dates from the db and highlight them in the calendar control (so users know there is a meeting on those days). The code that does that is

```
        if (ListDates.Contains(e.Day.Date))
        {
            e.Cell.CssClass = "highlight";
        }
```

The issue i have is when a user selects a date when a meeting is occurring (so this date has the css class `highlight` applied to it) it defaults to the controls color.

For that reason i decided to add a `newHighlight` css class so when a user **selects a date with a meeting scheduled** i would like to give it a new Css class (`newHighlight`).

To resolve this issue i added this code

```
        if (ListDates.Contains(Calendar1.SelectedDate))
        {
            e.Cell.CssClass = "newHighlight";
        }
```

The problem i have is selecting a date with a meeting highlights EVERY cell (the entire calendar) and not just the one cell which the user selected (which also has a meeting on that day)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to add a check in the second `if`:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListDates != null )
    {
        if (ListDates.Contains(e.Day.Date))
        {
            e.Cell.CssClass = "highlight";
        }

        if (ListDates.Contains(Calendar1.SelectedDate) && e.Day.Date == Calendar1.SelectedDate)
        {
            e.Cell.CssClass = "newHighlight";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I've been banging on at this for hours!!